# Правило расчета количества комбинаций

Tags: математика

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно рассчитать количество комбинаций в такой задаче:
Есть 3 станка, 3 возможных технологических процесса, по которым может производиться продукт, 3 варианта оснастки для каждого станка. Каждая операция из тех. процесса выполняется на одном станке.

Мне казалось, что это произведение факториалов 3! * 3! *3! *3!. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что все сложнее. Заранее огромное спасибо!

Comment: Лично мне задача кажется сформулированной неоднозначно. Например, продукт может быть один, но производиться последовательно тремя операциями на трех станках. Или это куча разных продуктов, которые производятся на каждом станке со своей оснасткой и технологическим процессом. Причем опять же неясно, все оснастки годятся для каждого процесса или нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Станок *А*, у него три оснастки - *1, 2, 3* для выполнения трех операций *a, b, c*

*A1a-A1b-A1c* - три возможных варианта операций с оснасткой 1

Добавляем еще две оснастки: 3+2*3=9 вариантов для станка *А*

Для трех станков: 9*9*9. Просто!

Хорошо бы... Так как в задаче ограничения не указаны (по использованию оснасток, по выполнению операций), то...

Оснасток у нас 9, операций тоже 9 (3станка*3техпроцесса). Конкретная оснастка под конкретную операцию. Да? Технологи могли прогуливать пары и не знать, как правильно, поэтому на какой станок какая оснастка попадет и какая операция на нем будет выполняться, неведомо. Значит, для одного станка А: 9*9=81 вариант использования всех 9 оснасток и выполнения возможных 9 операций.

Имеем три станка: 81*81*81

```
-----------------------------
```

Станков - *x*, оснасток на станок - *y*, техпроцессов - *z*

Всего оснасток Y=y*x (у вариантов оснастки для каждого станка)

Всего операций Z=z*x (каждая операция из тех. процесса выполняется на одном станке)

```
f=(Y*Z)^x=(y*z*x^2)^x
```

Comment: "Технологи
могли прогуливать пары и не знать, как
правильно, поэтому на какой станок какая
оснастка попадет и какая операция на нем будет выполняться, неведомо." Тонкий намек))у